# Problem in converting visio file to eps file for latex

Tags: eps, inkscape

I am now writing thesis using LaTeX. I tried Microsoft visio to draw flowcharts and wanted  to create `eps` file so as to incorporate in LaTeX document, while converting, I  face the following problems,

1. when I use `metafiletoeps.exe` converter, the fonts inside the flowchart get transformed as  a bitmap font rather than a vector font.

[image: Prob 1]

2. when I save the visio document as a `svg` file and reopened using inkscape, the fonts in the flowchart overlaps or goes out of flow chart symbol boundary.
   [image: Prob 2]
   [image: Prob 2]
3. when I print the visio document using pdfcreator to convert to `eps` file, the fonts inside the flowchart appeared as bitmap in the `eps` document.
   [image: Prob 3]

How can I get correct `eps` with fonts also in vector format in the conversion of visio docs to eps file format?

Comment: What version of Visio are you using? The newer versions should be able to save to pdf without additional software (like pdfcreator or Adobe Acrobat). Also, as you say you just started to write: You should consider switching to pdflatex, because it is able to inlcude png, jpg and pdf graphics driectly, which is usually easier than using eps.

Comment: If you are trying to make a flow chart, try tikz also. search in this site for flow charts.

Comment: @matth saved the visio document as pdf. The rendering in the saved pdf is good. But when i include  the same in my thesis, the rendering is not good. it appears to be bitmap.

Comment: @vivek Could you can add more information? Like stating what version of Visio you are using. Or posting a downloadable sample file. Otherwise it is more or less impossible to guess what the exact problem is.

Comment: @matth how to post a downloadable sample file?

Comment: You would have to upload your file to some [file hosting service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_hosting_service) and then post a link to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are interested to create the flowchart with PSTricks, I provide the following template.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\definecolor{Pink}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{psmatrix}
\renewcommand\PreviewBbAdjust{-8mm 7mm 9mm 1mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.6,colsep=0.5]
\psovalbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,shadow=true]{Begin} \\
\psdblframebox[framearc=.4,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink]{row2col1}\\
\psframebox[shadow=true]{row3col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{row3col2} \\
\psdiabox[shadow=true]{row4col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{row4col2} \\
\psframebox[shadow=true]{row5col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{row5col2}\\
\psframebox[shadow=true]{row6col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{\bf row6col2}&row6col3 \\
\psdblframebox[framearc=.4,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink]{row7col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{\bf row7col2}&row7col3\\

%top frame
\psframe[linestyle=dashed](-1,5.3)(2.35,2)
\rput{0}(-1.3,4.5){\rotateleft{TopFrame}}
\psframebox[shadow=true]{row8col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{\bf row8col2}&row6col3\\
\psframebox[shadow=true]{\begin{tabular}{c}row9col1-line1\\row9col1-line2\end{tabular}}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{\bf row9col2}&row9col3\\
\psframebox[shadow=true]{row10col1}&\psframebox[shadow=true]{row10col2}\\
row11col1\\
\psovalbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,shadow=true]{end} \\

\ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}
\ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}

\ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}
\ncline{4,2}{5,2}
\ncline{->}{4,1}{4,2}
\ncline{4,1}{5,1}
\ncline{->}{5,1}{6,1}
\ncline{->}{5,1}{6,2}

\ncline{->}{6,1}{7,1}
\ncline{->}{6,1}{6,2}
\ncline{->}{7,1}{8,1}
\ncline{->}{8,1}{9,1}
\ncline{->}{9,1}{10,1}
\ncline{->}{10,1}{11,1}
\ncline{->}{11,1}{12,1}

\ncline{->}{12,1}{12,2}

\ncline{->}{7,2}{8,2}
\ncline{->}{8,2}{9,2}
\ncline{->}{9,2}{10,2}

\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(5.2,7)(6.5,7)(6.5,8.3)(5.2,8.3)
\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(6.5,8.3)(6.5,5.8)(5.2, 5.8 )
\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(6.5,5.8)(6.5,4.4)(5.2,4.4)

\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround.
(but in a case you plan to provide `.eps` files to a conference volume editor, then this trick is not useful)

---

**Visio**

- Use Visio to adjust page size as per your drawing

  - File --> Page Setup --> Page Size --> `Size to fit drawing contents`. Apply and close this dialog box.
- Save the file as .PDF
- Open it and verify the contents.

**LaTeX**

- Use `\usepackage{epsfig}` in `.tex` file.
- Use `\includegraphics{<path>/<PDF_File_Name>} %(no file extension)`
- Get the generated `<PDF_File_Name>.PDF` file to the `<path>`, create a copy of it and
  rename it as `<PDF_File_Name>.eps`

Now build the `.tex`.
LaTeX nicely includes `<PDF_File_Name>.PDF` in to the LaTeX output.

---

**Edit 1**

> Working example:
>   Precondition: File1.PDF and File1.eps are present

```
% Using 'journal' as a document class to compile the .tex file.
% Workaround is is not related to this class.
\documentclass{journal}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{File1}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**: Added comment for usage of `journal` class.

Comment: why `journal` documentclass?

Comment: @Troy Thank you, forgot to add a comment in the code.